# In Backbone model my nested object is automatically converted into JSON which was a model before

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, model, backbone-model

I have a backbone model(say ModelA) in which I defined set of validation functions. In all validation functions I pass model attributes as arguments. This validations get invoked on each step of wizard. This wizard has one model defined for it.

```
validations: {
    validateFuncA: function(attrs) {
        //Here property1 is sometimes look like model and sometimes an object. As a result I get an error "property1.get is not a function" because property1 is object at that time and can be accessed using property1.value.  
        var obj1 = attrs.property1.get('value');
    }
}
```

So I am not able to figure out why this property is getting converted to an Object. These validations get invoked when I click on submit button on last page of wizard. In all the previous steps property1 looks like model but after submit action it looks like an object.

Did anyone encounter with such an issue. I am doing something wrong but not able to find it out.

Also observed that this case is only one particular property and not all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behavior of `backbone.js`.

The project https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model would solve this problem for you because it overrides this behavior by instead doing something equivalent to the following:

*Note: following code is untested, but should get you in the intended direction*

```
var child = new Backbone.Model({iAm: 'aChild'});
var parent = new Backbone.Model({iHave: child});

// 1. Assign the existing save method somewhere so we can use it.
var swizzledSave = parent.save;

// 2. Override the save method
parent.save = function(attrs, options, ctxt) {

    attrs = attrs || this.attributes;
    var toSend = {};

    // 3. For each attribute in the model
    _.each(attrs, function(attrVal, attrKey) {
         // 4. If the attribute has the type Backbone.Model, call it's save method (which has not been overridden by the way)
         if (attrVal instanceof Backbone.Model)
               attrVal.save();

         // 5. Otherwise, add this attribute to a list of attributes that can be sent to the server
         else
               toSend[attrKey] = attrVal;
    }, this);

    // 6. Send only those attributes.
    swizzledSave(toSend, options, ctxt);
}
```

Comment: So this behavior would be usually after the request is sent ??

Comment: No, see edit... maybe I don't fully grasp your needs, but the idea is that we make multiple calls to the server allowing each model to independently `save`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve it in this manner: Although it's naive but solved my purpose.

```
if(attrs.property1.value === undefined){
    value = attrs.property1.get('value'));
}else{
    modules = attrs.property1.value;
}
```

Comment: That works but you'll regret it if you keep doing that because it is breaking the intent of the `backbone.js` properties system. If you're not using `this.get` and `this.set` you are bypassing the interface that triggers events and so on.

Comment: Edit: maybe you're doing it right, I don't know without seeing more code, but the core idea at least is right - you need to specify waht to send.

Comment: I am using this data to validate some stuff on UI. Not modifying underlying backbone model while posting request. I will try your approach as well. @tacos_tacos_tacos

Comment: It took me a while to fully appreciate the use of `Event` in `backbone.js` but they save a lot of time. If you directly set an attribute then it may prevent it from triggering the `change` event